# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ( name of method)

Tags: java

I keep getting an error that says Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ( name of the method). I created a class called Creature and created a constructor and I just created an array to store the name of the creature inside the constructor but it's just not working. I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much.

```
//here is my constructor but it's in another class (class creature).


public Creature(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        /*
         * random function returns a value between 0.0 and 1 adding 1 makes sure that 0
         * is never returned Math.floor manages to return integer value closest and
         * smaller to the current value e.g 3.45 -> on floor function 3 is the answer
         */
        foodUnits = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1); // get a value from 1 - 12
        healthUnits = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1); // get a random value from 1 - 7
        firePowerUnits = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 11); // get a random value from 0 - 10
        // normalize units function
        dateCreated = new Date();
        dateDied = null;

        // keeps track of how many creatures are alive
        numStillAlive += 1; // adding to an alive creature to the class

    }



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NumOfCreatures;
        String NameOfCreature;

        Creature[] c = new Creature[NumOfCreatures];

        System.out.println("[------------------------------------------------]\n" + "[ Welcome to the Battle Game ]\n"
                + "[------------------------------------------------] ");
        do {
            System.out.println("How many creatures would you like to have (minimum 2, maximum 8)?");

            NumOfCreatures = sc.nextInt();
            if (NumOfCreatures < 2 || NumOfCreatures > 8) {
                System.out.println("*** Illegal number of creatures requested *** ");
            }
        } while (NumOfCreatures < 2 || NumOfCreatures > 8);

        for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfCreatures; i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the name of creature " + i + "?");
            NameOfCreature = sc.nextLine();
            c[i] = NameOfCreature;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full stacktrace of the error, so we can see which line it's triggering on?

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem `c[i] = NameOfCreature;` you are trying to save a `String` to a `Creature` array.

Instead you need to do it something like this:

```
//Create a new Creature using the input
Creature myCreature = new Creature(NameOfCreature);
//Now assign the Creature to the array
c[i] = myCreature;
```

Caution you also have a problem with the size of the `Creature` array on this line `Creature[] c = new Creature[NumOfCreatures];`because the value of `NumOfCreatures` is undefined when your program runs (you dont set the value until later in your code). So what you need to do is create the array size after you get the creature number like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int NumOfCreatures;
    String NameOfCreature;
    
    //Don't set the size here, just create the object
    Creature[] c;

    System.out.println("[------------------------------------------------]\n" + "[ Welcome to the Battle Game ]\n"
            + "[------------------------------------------------] ");
    
    //Get the creature number so we can define the array size
    do {
        System.out.println("How many creatures would you like to have (minimum 2, maximum 8)?");

        NumOfCreatures = sc.nextInt();
        if (NumOfCreatures < 2 || NumOfCreatures > 8) {
            System.out.println("*** Illegal number of creatures requested *** ");
        }
    } while (NumOfCreatures < 2 || NumOfCreatures > 8);
    
    //Now that we know the number of creatures we can set the array size
    c = new Creature[NumOfCreatures];

    //Then we can fill the array
    for (int i = 1; i <= NumOfCreatures; i++) {
        System.out.println("What is the name of creature " + i + "?");
        NameOfCreature = sc.nextLine();
        //Create a new Creature using the input
        Creature myCreature = new Creature(NameOfCreature);
        //Now assign the Creature to the array
        c[i] = myCreature;
    }
```